# CSS zoom breaks caretRangeFromPoint in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, html, css, microsoft-edge

When changing the CSS zoom level on the body element of the document in Edge, the caretRangeFromPoint returns an incorrect range.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.zoom = 1.5;
window.onclick = function(e) {
    var caretPos = document.caretRangeFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        var obj = document.createElement('span');
        obj.style.cssText = 'background: #0c0;display: inline-block;height: 1em;width:1em;';
    if (caretPos)
        caretPos.insertNode(obj);
};
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Aw9aV/292/

Click inside the `<p>` element to see the issue in action. The span is not inserted in the clicked location.

**Update**

I contacted Microsoft about this issue. They are still investigating but there initial findings indicates that it might be a bug in Edge. The contact person informed me that he is unable to replicate it in the RS5 update of Windows. I am now waiting for more information as to how this will be fixed in the Webview control.

Comment: Which version of edge you are using??

Comment: Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything in JSFiddle for me even after deleting the first line setting zoom to 1.5, I'm not sure there is an existing breakpoint for you to use the function against with your current code. At any rate, you may already know this, but `caretRangeFromPoint` is non-standard, so I would not recommend using it except in experimental code.

Comment: What do you mean does not do anything? If you click inside the <p> element it should insert a span, coloured green. If you run the fiddle from EDGE you will note that the span is not inserted in the clicked location.

Comment: Also, per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/caretRangeFromPoint this function is supported from version 12 of EDGE onwards.

Comment: @Freddie I am running it in Firefox 61, which is also listed as supporting it since Firefox 20; perhaps the support table is wrong, then? Firefox seems to work fine with `caretPositionFromPoint`, though (just to insert the node, not inserting the node in combo with zoom applied).

Comment: @TylerH I did not test this in Firefox. We are using it in a webview embedded in a UWP app. So EDGE is the only browser I need to get this to work in.

Comment: (FYI - Edge is not all-caps).

Comment: It is when you are shouting it out of frustration.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have Edge in my system(Using Ubuntu) I think this code from MDN might help

> ```
> function insertBreakAtPoint(e) {
>
>     var range;
>     var textNode;
>     var offset;
>
>     if (document.caretPositionFromPoint) {
>         range = document.caretPositionFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
>         textNode = range.offsetNode;
>         offset = range.offset;
>         
>     } else if (document.caretRangeFromPoint) {
>         range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
>         textNode = range.startContainer;
>         offset = range.startOffset;
>     }
>
>     // only split TEXT_NODEs
>     if (textNode && textNode.nodeType == 3) {
>         var replacement = textNode.splitText(offset);
>          var br = document.createElement('span');
>         br.style.cssText = 'background: #0c0;display: inline-block;height: 1em;width:1em;';
>         textNode.parentNode.insertBefore(br, replacement);
>     }
> }
>
> var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
> for (i=0 ; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
>     paragraphs[i].addEventListener("click", insertBreakAtPoint, false);
> }
> ```

For more information visit [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/caretRangeFromPoint)
I have also created a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/edx_narendra/0v1dc94L/2/) please check and let me know you concern

Comment: Like the original code it works until you change the css zoom level on the body tag of the document. Then the ranges are thrown off.